# NSButton - setEnabled from another Class not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton

I am relatively new to Objective-C and Cocoa so please excuse me if this is too obvious or if my terminology is incorrect. I have searched documentation and the web thoroughly without finding the answer. I have been sending messages to methods from other classes without issue until now.

I have two classes: `MainWindowController` and `ServerControl`.

I have an instance method within `MainWindowController` called `startServer` that looks like the following:

```
- (void)startServer 
{
    NSLog(@"Running startServer from MainWindowController");
    [startButton setEnabled:NO];
    [restartButton setEnabled:YES];
    [shutdownButton setEnabled:YES];
}
```

When I send a message to `startServer` from within `MainWindowController` from another instance method I get the expected result: `NSLog` executes and the three `NSButton`s are enabled and disabled correctly.

When I send a message to `startServer` from within `ServerControl` inside an instance method like this:

```
// Update buttons
MainWindowController *mainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] init];
[mainWindowController startServer];
```

What happens is that `NSLog` executes but the `NSButton`s don't get enabled and disabled as expected.

I have also tried using properties and setting the `setEnabled` option from within the `ServerControl` class and that doesn't work either.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: `ServerControl` needs the pointer to the already-created instance of `MainWindowController`. Making a new instance of `MainWindowController` with `alloc/init` won't have any effect on the buttons that are being displayed by the true `MainWindowController`.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense! Can you tell me how to reference already created instances or point me in the direction of documentation? I'm searching right now.

Comment: I recommend searching for protocols and delegates. The `ServerControl` object needs a `delegate` property. At the point where you `alloc/init` the `ServerControl` object, set the delegate property to point to the `MainWindowController`.  Then you can use the delegate property to call methods in the `MainWindowController`.

Comment: BTW, if you haven't already, it's a good idea to watch the CS193P videos.  There's a link to the videos at the top of the Getting Started forum on Apple's developer forums.

Comment: Thank you again. I think that's enough information to figure it out.

Comment: Another issue here could be that you are referencing the buttons before the view loads. IBOutlet will only be valid after viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: Do you present or push mainWindowController to the view hierarchy after you call [mainWindowController staryServer]?

Comment: @proxi The view is fully loaded before these buttons are referenced.

Comment: @Greg I'm not sure what you mean. The [mainWindowController startServer]; code is within an instance method that is an IBAction. When a NSButton is pressed, it calls that IBAction method inside the ServerControl class which executes some code and before I attempt to enable / disable other buttons.

Comment: BTW, I wanted to let everyone know that I got it working by using a different method. Amazing what a little bit of sleep will do for you. I am already storing a boolean value of isRunning for when the server is running in Core Data so I just used IB's bindings to bind the Enabled state to the boolean value and then used NSNegateBoolean for the one button that I wanted to be reversed. I still need to learn a lot but the result is what I wanted.